# Deleted Objects Container does not exist, even after enabling Recycle Bin

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2022

I have used the following commands to enable recycle bin:

```
$ForestName = (Get-ADDomain).Forest
Enable-ADOptionalFeature -Identity 'Recycle Bin Feature' -Scope ForestOrConfigurationSet -Target $ForestName -Confirm:$false
```

The command ran successfully, but a "Deleted Objects" container was not created.

As a test, I have created a user, waited for it to be synced to all dcs, and then deleted it. Even then no Deleted Objects container was created.

`(Get-ADDomain).DeletedObjectsContainer` returns `CN=Deleted Objects,DC=domain,DC=com"` (which doesn't exist).

The forest level is 2016, all dcs are windows server 2022. (freshly installed)

What should I have done differently and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you looking in the Active Directory Administrative Center? Show the output of **Get-ADOptionalFeature -Filter 'name -like "Recycle Bin Feature"'**

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `Deleted Objects` container does indeed exist, but it is not shown in the AD Users MMC Snap-In nor in the ADSI Snap-In.

Items in the container can be listed using:

```
Get-ADObject -SearchBase ((Get-ADDomain).DeletedObjectsContainer) -Filter "*" -IncludeDeletedObjects
```

I think the reason that the container is not shown is that itself is marked as deleted.

I got no idea why that is the case, but knowing that atleast solved this riddle for me.